# Is the current Date/Time format retrievable?

Tags: command-line, programming, time, date

My task bar shows "Sat Feb 9, 5:41 PM". Where does Ubuntu store the current Date/Time format information? Is it retrievable?

I will be programming in Java, and would like to access the current format set by the user.

Comment: Hi Peter, just curious, but did you notice you've got answers? Curious if it works for you (any).

Comment: @PeterStone what if the users uses clockoverride extension??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java uses  [`java.util.Locale` objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) in most calls dealing with formatting output for the user. There is a default Locale (`Locale.getDefault()`) which ought to be what the current user specified in the system settings. Otherwise you can use the `LANGUAGE` or `LANG` environment variables as input for `new Locale(String)`.

Note that you can have specific locales for specific output:

```
LC_ADDRESS
LC_IDENTIFICATION
LC_MEASUREMENT
LC_MONETARY
LC_NAME
LC_NUMERIC
LC_PAPER
LC_TELEPHONE
LC_TIME
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is, with the command:

```
locale date_fmt
```

The output will look like:

```
%a %e %b %Y %k:%M:%S %Z
```

To see what it means:

```
date --help
```

See also [here](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-locale/) and [here](https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/tools/use-the-date-command-in-linux/).

I wouldn't be surprised if there existed a library in Java retrieving the info with a built in wrapper though instead of a system call.